# Is __proto__ is a property of an object instance or its a property of Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I try to understand prototype and gain a clear understanding so fur. Which i do not understand is that,
is `__proto__` is a property of an `object instance` or its a property of `Object.prototype` which we can use from object instance . I know other aspect about prototype and prototype chain and only want to know specifically that who won `__proto__` actually ? Is its owner is every `object instance` or `Object constructor` (which we have to call new) prototype ?

Comment: `obj = {}; objs.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") //false`

Comment: You can also view all property names of an object with: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)` ...and it includes `__proto__`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: And see it in the ECMAScript spec here: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__

Comment: if you go up the proto chain like this `obj = {}; obj.__proto__` you will see the base object witch every object in javascript inherit from if you check now `obj.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") // true`

Comment: @slappy , Yeah, now its clear that Object.prototype have __proto__ property but object instance haven't. Thank you very much.

Comment: Forget all you know about `__proto__`, pretend that it doesn't exist. Only use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Obect.setPrototypeOf` which access the *internal [[prototype]]* property of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> The `__proto__` property of `Object.prototype` is an accessor property (a getter function and a setter function) that exposes the internal [[Prototype]] (either an object or null) of the object through which it is accessed.

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')); // false
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')); // true
```

`__proto__` is somewhat deprecated. It's better to use:

1. [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) - create a new object, using an existing object as the prototype
2. [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get an object's prototype
3. [setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to set it's prototype